# What is Bayesians' equivalence of sample size determination?

Tags: bayesian, sample-size, statistical-power

Under the frequentist framework, one can use power analysis to determine sample size for a given effect size, significance level, and power. How are similar questions answered under Bayesian framework?

Comment: What fun. Well, let's begin with a comment *power*, which is defined as the probability that we do not make a Type II error, or that we do not reject the null hypothesis when the null is false.  But *Type I* and *Type II* and *hypothesis testing* and *reject* and *fail-to-reject* and therefore *power* are all frequentist notions. So you've kind of stacked the deck here! No matter.  Bayesian equivalents can be found for all.

Comment: As I was preparing a long-ish answer, I noticed that this question has been asked and answered many times at Cross Validated. I'll survey the previous answers and will only comment if I can add something that the others cannot.

Comment: I should also point out that the power calculation in the frequentist framework also requires a definition of the population standard deviation, without which standard errors cannot be calculated, so $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\sigma$, $\delta$ and $N$ are the five values, and any four need to be specified to uniquely define the fifth . . . in frequentist statistics.